# Pandas Compare CSV

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

I have to compare two CSV files in Python using pandas

There are two CSV file containing Product code in different form
First way:-

```
LYSB00LW3ZL3K-ELECTRNCS
LYSB00LW3ZL3K-ELECTRNCS- Standard Packaging- W20 - Dual Driver
LYSB01KH2MDPU-ELECTRNCS
LYSB01KH2MDPU-ELECTRNCS- Small Bangle
LYSB01KH2MDPU-ELECTRNCS- Large Bangle
LYSB06XXD7NYY-ELECTRNCS- Large
LYSB06XXD7NYY-ELECTRNCS- Small
LYSB01KM4T0PO-ELECTRNCS
```

Second way:- 
(if you remove LYS for above product code and all the thing after - ) the second form is present)

```
B00LW3ZL3K
B01KH2MDPU
```

so I have to compare both file and make new csv file with the first column as Product Code and second column as Status

Result should give output in 2 different case

1) If B00LW3ZL3K(product code) exist in the second file it should return all belonging product code from the first file and their status as 'Product in stock'

2) If B01KM4T0PO(product code) not exist in the second file it should return all belonging product code from the first file and their status as  'Product out of stock'

```
Output:
In-Stock
    LYSB00LW3ZL3K-ELECTRNCS
    LYSB00LW3ZL3K-ELECTRNCS- Standard Packaging- W20 - Dual Driver
    LYSB01KH2MDPU-ELECTRNCS
    LYSB01KH2MDPU-ELECTRNCS- Small Bangle
    LYSB01KH2MDPU-ELECTRNCS- Large Bangle

Out-of-Stock
   LYSB06XXD7NYY-ELECTRNCS- Large
   LYSB06XXD7NYY-ELECTRNCS- Small
   LYSB01KM4T0PO-ELECTRNCS
```

Comment: So you know about pandas, but do you have any code yet?

Comment: @cricket_007 **not much**

Comment: By the way, Sqlite might make more sense for querying /filtering than csv files

Comment: @cricket_007 this what I was trying to do

Comment: @cricket_007 but I have data in csv file only :(

Comment: @cricket_007 I have edited my question and added my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-This is my solution for this problem

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import os


class Update(object):
    def __init__(self, category):
        """Path to file"""
        masterfile = os.path.realpath('lys_masterfile.txt')
        update_file = os.path.realpath('Outputs/liveyoursport/Update_Spider/{}_Update.csv'.format(category))
        self.comparision(masterfile, update_file, category)

    def comparision(self, output_file, update_file, category):
        ''' Function to extract correct data by category '''
        sku_dict = {
            'Electronics': 'ELECTRNCS',
            'Sports Equipment': 'SPRTSEQIP',
            'Health and Beauty': 'HLTHBTY',
            "Women's Fashion Accessories": 'WMNFSHACCSS',
            'Toys and Games': 'TOYS',
            "Men's Fashion Shoes": 'MNFSHSHOE',
            "Other Sports Shoes": 'OTHSPRTSSHOE',
            "Women's Sports Shoes": 'WMNSPORTSHOE',
            "Men's Running Shoes": 'MNSRUNSHOE',
            "Amazon Global-Toys": 'GLBTOYS',
            "Women's Running Shoes": 'WMNRUNSHOE',
            "Women's Fashion Shoes": 'WMNFSHSHOE',
            "Computer & Accessories": 'CMPTRACCS',
            "Office Supplies": "OFFSUPPLIES",
            "Clothing Accessories": "CLTHACCSS",
            "TigerDirect": "TDRCT"
        }
        sku = sku_dict.get(category)

        def extraction(value):
            if isinstance(value, str) and sku in value:
                asin = value.split('-')[0].replace('LYS', '')
                return asin
            else:
                return 'None'

        """Extract only necessary field from file """
        masterfile_sku = pd.read_csv(output_file, usecols=['Product Code/SKU'], delimiter='\t', skip_blank_lines=True)

        """ Trying to extract SKU """
        masterfile_asin = masterfile_sku['Product Code/SKU'].apply(extraction)

        """ Making another dataFrame for comparision """
        products_df = pd.DataFrame(
            {'sku': masterfile_asin, 'Product Code/SKU': masterfile_sku['Product Code/SKU']}).query("sku != 'None'")

        """Fetching Update file and separating in_stock and out_stock """
        update_df = pd.read_csv(update_file, usecols=[2, 3], names=['sku', 'price'])
        update_in_stock_df = update_df.query("price != 'nan'")
        update_out_stock_df = update_df.query("price == 'nan'")

        """ Check for instock Product """
        in_stock = pd.merge(products_df, update_in_stock_df, on='sku', how='inner')
        # print in_stock

        """ Check for out-of-stock Product """
        out_of_stock = pd.merge(in_stock, products_df, on='sku', how='right', indicator=True).query(
            "_merge == 'right_only'")
        out_of_stock = pd.merge(out_of_stock, update_out_stock_df, on='sku', how='outer')
        out_of_stock = out_of_stock.drop_duplicates(subset='sku')

        """Writing all dataFrames"""
        in_stock.to_csv(os.path.realpath('Outputs/liveyoursport/in_stock/Lys_{}_in_stock.csv'.format(category)))
        out_of_stock.to_csv(
            os.path.realpath('Outputs/liveyoursport/out_of_stock/Lys_{}_out_of_stock.csv'.format(category)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = datetime.datetime.now()
    Update("Women's Running Shoes")
    print 'Done'
    print 'Completed in {}'.format(datetime.datetime.now() - a)
```